# Adding an where clause breaks the query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to debug this for quite a while now with no success.

It seems that my mySQL query breaks as soon as I add a where clause to the below query.

Note this returns no results when it should:

```
SELECT * FROM `workorders` WHERE (`status`='Open') AND 
 `job_site_name` LIKE '%".$searchword."%'  ORDER BY `date_promised` ASC LIMIT 20
```

This is the same query without the where clause and it returns results as expected, but I need the where `status=Open` as part of the query...

```
SELECT * FROM `workorders` WHERE 
 `job_site_name` LIKE '%".$searchword."%'  ORDER BY `date_promised` ASC LIMIT 20
```

Furthermore, this works (and shows that the status column exists and works in other cases):

```
SELECT * FROM `workorders` WHERE (`status`='Open') AND `invoice_number` LIKE 
  '%".$searchword."%'  ORDER BY `date_promised` ASC LIMIT 20
```

I appreciate any assistance in identifying the cause of this problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: how does your second query return results when it's missing a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Your queries don't make sense. You have a rogue AND in #2.

I would also be weary of the type of quotes that you are using. Are you copy and pasting from Word or anything, why do you have 2 different types of quotes anyway?

Comment: @Shackrock - back ticks are a valid way of making sure column names are read by mysql (especially if you're using reserved words).

Comment: That was a typo. Query #2 works fine. See Edited. Query #1 is the one I am having trouble with.

Comment: Any reason for the parentheses? They are usually used for wrapping 2 or more conditions. Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: @Ben, Not getting any errors. Errors messages would be nice.

Comment: please only post relevant code, if only 1 is broke, only post 1. you dont see errors if you don't check for them, mysql is not php

Comment: remove the parentheses

Comment: Probably no rows match both the conditions: `(status='Open') AND 
 job_site_name LIKE '%".$searchword."%'` ?

Comment: Parens don't change anything as far as the result set returned, they certainly don't hurt.

Comment: There is a match however!!

Comment: Can you please output the *generated* HTML, without the PHP variable? Just to check if there's anything wrong there..

Comment: Does the match also have status 'Open'?

Comment: Please post the full echo statement you're using.  The query is 'good' so like others have said either the query is returning 0 records, or you have some silly mistake in your PHP.  So post it and I will make some self-deprecating remark when I point out your error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be both criteria are not met. If you need to use an `OR` clause then you can do

```
SELECT * 
FROM `workorders` 
WHERE (`status`='Open' 
   OR `job_site_name` LIKE '%".$searchword."%')
ORDER BY `date_promised` ASC 
LIMIT 20
```